# How to UPDATE COLUMN with a condition FROM another table in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

**table1**

```
CATEGORY | RANGE    | PERCENTAGE
 REG     | 250001   | 50
 REG     | 500001   | 40
 REG     | 9999999  | 30
 VIP     | 5001     | 50
 VIP     | 10001    | 40
 VIP     | 9999999  | 30
```

**table 2**

```
CATEGORY | PRICE    | DISCOUNT
 REG     | 100000   |  0
 REG     | 400000   |  0
 REG     | 600000   |  0
 VIP     | 3000     |  0
 VIP     | 6000     |  0
 VIP     | 120000   |  0
```

I would like to update `DISCOUNT` in `table 2` based on `RANGE` and `PERCENTAGE` from `table 1`

**CATEGORY REG**

```
WHEN PRICE is  <= 250001
DISCOUNT = PRICE * 50%
WHEN PRICE is  > 250001 AND <= 500001
DISCOUNT = PRICE * 40%
WHEN PRICE is  > 500001
DISCOUNT = PRICE * 30%
```

**CATEGORY VIP**

```
WHEN PRICE is  <= 5001 
DISCOUNT = PRICE * 50% 
WHEN PRICE is  > 10001 AND <= 500001
DISCOUNT = PRICE * 40% 
WHEN PRICE is  > 100001
DISCOUNT = PRICE * 30%
```

Comment: Use Case when to do.

Comment: is this for `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Comment: mysql workbench :D

Comment: ok. I can only provide solution for `SQL Server`. Not familiar with `mysql` at all

Comment: Seems to me that in the long run you might be better served with an **extra discount table** (instead of an unwieldy `case` construct) you can join your tables to. That way you will not "hard code" the discount into your table but can change it easily to whatever your current policy requires.

Comment: actually i don't need to "hard code" the discount, what i need to do is to get the percentage in table1 that will meet the condition i posted. RANGE is given in table1 with it's PERCENTAGE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query for category 'REG'. You can change where category and condition in WHEN clause according your requirement.

```
UPDATE table2 
SET discount = CASE 
    WHEN price <= 250001 THEN ((price*50)/100)
    WHEN (price BETWEEN 250002 AND 500001) THEN ((price*40)/100)
    WHEN price > 500001 THEN ((price*30)/100)
    ELSE discount 
END
WHERE category = 'REG'
```

Check updated query for category 'REG':

```
UPDATE table2 SET discount = 
(SELECT ((price*a.percentage)/100) FROM table1 as a WHERE price <= a.range AND category='REG' LIMIT 1) 
WHERE category = 'REG'
```

Check with below query (Edit#2):

```
UPDATE table2 AS b SET discount = 
(SELECT ((b.price*a.percentage)/100) FROM table1 as a WHERE a.range >= b.price AND a.category=b.category LIMIT 1)
```

Make sure range column is quoted because range is a MYSQL reserved keyword. Also note that datatype of range column should be integer.

Comment: You could do like: 

    UPDATE table2 
SET discount = (SELECT CASE 
    WHEN price <= 250001 THEN ((price*a.percentage)/100)
    ELSE discount 
END
FROM table1 as a WHERE a.range=250001)
WHERE category = 'REG'

Comment: @ZoHaNCheck updated query in my answer. You need to change CATEGORY from 'REG' to 'VIP' to update VIP category discounts.

Comment: thanks. tried but not working. should UPDATED table2 based on RANGE and PERCENTAGE from table1.

Comment: @ZoHaN It should. This will update 'discount' column of 'table2' where category is 'REG' with the value as percentage amount of 'price' column selecting percentage and range of table1. Can you show me your query?

Comment: @ZoHaN Check Edit#2 and let us know the issue with the query if you not satisfy with the answers of anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table2 t2 SET 
DISCOUNT = (
    SELECT max(t1.`percentage`) * t2.price / 100 FROM table1 t1
    WHERE
        t1.category = t2.category AND
        t2.price < t1.`range`
)
```

Comment: i need to update table2 by getting the percentage in table1.

Comment: So what is the `data type` for `percentage` column ?

Comment: decimal. yes it should be divided into 100 and multiply by the PRICE but PERCENTAGE should get from table1.

Comment: Why? what is the problem ?